# Laravel, Authenticated method don't get called when auto login

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing auto login using either of these 2 ways

```
$user = User::find($userId);
Auth::login($user);
```

or

```
Auth::loginUsingId($userId, TRUE);
```

Both way Authenticated event don't fire.

I have implemented Authenticated method in LoginController

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{    
     Log::debug('Authenticated Called for user ' . $user->username);
}
```

my login controller defination

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

How to make it work?

Comment: which event are you expecting to be fired and how do you know it isn't being fired?

Comment: authenticated method get fired when i login using the form, log get written, but when i try to auto login, this method don't get fired

Comment: of course not, because you are directly logging in ... tihs method only gets fired by the `login` method of the `LoginController` through the `sendLoginResponse` method in the default setup, you would have to be calling this method yourself if you are not having that method handle the request... what event are you expecting to be fired

Comment: @lagbox  all i want, when user login is complete, i need to run some checks, so i need some function where i can implement it? can u guide where i can write?

Comment: write now i have it implemented in the Authenticated method, and its working fine, but as i have to use auto login, my code is not working

Comment: yea you can listen for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` event and do what you would like ... I have no idea where you are doing this logging in you are talking about, but if it is in the `LoginController` you could call that `authenticated` method yourself

Comment: protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{    
     Log::debug('Authenticated Called for user ' . $user->username);
}
Talking about this , just log in file

Comment: alright, that is some options for you ... good luck

Comment: I know it and old post, but I'm faced with the exact situation and am wondering which avenue @IrfanZafar decided to go with and his impressions.
What I know is auth/events are all fired at each access requiring authentication while the trait authenticated method is fired only once when authenticating via the LoginController. 
I need to have a piece of code executed only when authenticating for the "first time" either via the LoginController or the auto-login method (Auth::login()).